# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email') with registration

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have problem with my if. There is my code:
`

```
app.post('/register', redirectHome, async (req, res, next)=>{
    try{
        const email = req.body.email;
        let password = req.body.password;

        emaildb = await db.getUserByEmail(email);

        const isValidEmail = compareSync(email, emaildb.email);
        
        if(isValidEmail){
            err_msg = 'registration done';
            return res.render('register.ejs', {err_msg: err_msg});
            
        }
        else{
            err_msg = 'User already exists!';
            return res.render('register.ejs', {err_msg: err_msg});
        }
```

`

There is probably issue with compare, because when I write existing in db email I see "User already exists!" and also when I write not existing in db email I see "User already exists!". So my if condition doesn't work well.

Comment: What debugging have you done? What is the value of `email` throughout that code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Can you post the `getUserByEmail` function and the result of `console.log(body)`?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a case that you do not have an user with a given email, for which emaildb is null or undefined. Then when you are calling the function compareSync(email, emaildb.email), here emaildb.email is undefined, for which you are not able to compare email and emaildb.email and throws "cannot read properties of undefined", also returning false.

```
 try{
        const email = req.body.email;
        let password = req.body.password;
    
        emaildb = await db.getUserByEmail(email);
        
        if(!emaildb){
           // do your work since no user exist with given email
           // return
        }
        else{
            err_msg = 'User already exists!';
            return res.render('register.ejs', {err_msg: err_msg});
        }
```